# One server cooklieless true or false

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

I've looked at questions such as [Set Sessionstate cookieless="true" in asp .Net, is the sessions state maintained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233287/set-sessionstate-cookieless-true-in-asp-net-is-the-sessions-state-maintained) and [Which one is better, InProc or SQL Server, for Session State mode in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688047/which-one-is-better-inproc-or-sql-server-for-session-state-mode-in-asp-net) but wondered if there an advantage or disadvantage to cookieless in true vs. false mode assuming everything is on one server.

We're looking to have around 200 people a day register and login, mainly text with some small PDF uploads (2Mb at most and say 5 documents).

Is there any upside to show set Cookieless to True in this or any instant (again assuming one server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't, not for that small amount of users anyway, unless they are using clients that does not allow or support client side cookies.

If you choose cookie based sessions, the InProc is fast, StateServer slow (but works for a server farm (multiple servers)):

Have a look at these post as well, especially the first one

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17719/what-risks-do-cookieless-sessions-have-what-are-the-mitigations/17733
- [ASP.NET session vs session state and cookies vs cookie less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189563/asp-net-session-vs-session-state-and-cookies-vs-cookie-less)
- [What are cookieless sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273066/what-are-cookieless-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

StateServer mode is best.

It will not lost session variable values.

**Also cookieless=true session is best, because coockieless=false will generate sessionstring in url path.**

Any one can copy that url path to access website from other computer.

Comment: "cookieless" is the other way around: cookieless = without cookies = session id encoded in URL